# Scriptable PE resource editor

Tags: windows, portable-executable, resource-editor

I need a tool that's commandline and which supports retrieving version information from the resources of a PE executable and also patch the binary with a new version. What I need to do is to automate incrementing the version of a PE binary.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resource Tools library [[1](http://alax.info/blog/1361), [2](http://alax.info/blog/category/utilities/resource-tools)] with COM interface. You can use it from VBScript/JScript and automate patching of version information as I already do.

Import/browse DLL type library to see COM interface syntax and below is code snippet for automation of VersionInfo patching.

```js
WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WScript.Echo("Current Directory: " + WshShell.CurrentDirectory);
Image = new ActiveXObject("AlaxInfo.ResourceTools.Image");
Image.Initialize(WshShell.CurrentDirectory + "\\Sample.dll");
WScript.Echo("Product Version: " + Image.VersionInfo.ProductVersionString);
WScript.Echo("File Version: " + Image.VersionInfo.FileVersionString);

VersionString = Image.VersionInfo.FileVersionString;
VersionString = VersionString.replace(" ", "");
VersionString = VersionString.replace(",", ".");
if(/([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)/i.exec(VersionString) == null)
  throw "Incorrect version string";
V1 = new Number(RegExp.$1);
V2 = new Number(RegExp.$2);
V3 = new Number(RegExp.$3);
V4 = new Number(RegExp.$4);
WScript.Echo("File Version Components: " + V1 + ", " + V2 + ", " + V3 + ", " + V4);
V4++;
VersionString = V1 + "." + V2 + "." + V3 + "." + V4;
WScript.Echo("New File Version: " + VersionString);

Image.VersionInfo.SetFileVersion(V1 * 65536 + V2, V3 * 65536 + V4);
Image.VersionInfo.SetString(0, "FileVersion", VersionString);
Image.VersionInfo.Update();
Image.EndUpdate(false);
```

The library is basically a wrapper over [`BeginUpdateResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648030%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and friends providing you with automation interface into patching not only numbers but other version info components, strings, bitmaps.

Comment: This looks like what I need, indeed. However, I can't get the ResourceTools to install properly (tried both Win8 and Win7, 64bit), with a test file that only does `new ActiveXObject("AlaxInfo.ResourceTools.Image")`. I'm getting an error, "Automation server can't create object". If I regsvr32 the .dll, then I get:  "Invalid value for registry". Any idea how to get this working? (sorry, I'm kinda clueless when it comes to COM...)

Comment: You need `1` install Win32 and/or x64 version from Administrative command prompt, elevated privileges `2` when running `.js` scripts make sure to run `cscript.exe` of proper bitness, e.g. for Win32 on 64-bit Windows you will run `C:\Windows\syswow64\cscript.exe myscript.js`.

Comment: So it doesn't work for me on Windows 7/8, 64 bit. Installed with admin privileges, running with the right cscript, etc., same errors. However, it seems to work on a clean Windows XP 32-bit install (I still had to regsvr32 the .dll), so I guess it sort of acceptable. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about Win 8, but it surely works in Win 7, both 32/64 bit.